# How to close a window pop up when its opened by Click Link in Robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

While executing a Test Case in RIDE, I clicked a link as

```
Click Link ${MAND}
```

and then it opens a window, after that I want to close the Window for that am using

`Click Button Close` / `Close Window`

none of these are helping me to close the window.
Once the window is opened it is not doing any operations.
I would like to do:

```
Click Link ${MAND}
Click Button Close
```

I am not able to perform the operations within the window. Is it because of the `Click Link` its directly opening a window, or do I need to write something for the window before I close it.
I have tried:

```
Execute Javascript document.getElementById("aspnetForm").click();

Click Button Close

Close Window
```

I dont think I am able to take control of the newly opened window.

Answer (score 0):

You want to select the window before closing it

```
 ${windows}= Get Window Names
 select window cc
 sleep 1s
 close window
```

Comment: any reason for the sleep?

Comment: I tried below :
 Select Window    title=View Commands
    sleep    4s
    click Button    Close


And got the below error in RIDE:
INFO : Clicking button 'Close'.
20161230 17:23:55.389 : FAIL : 
NoSuchWindowException: Message: Unable to get browser

20161230 17:23:55.390 : WARN : 
Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: NoSuchWindowException: Message: Unable to get browser

20161230 17:23:55.392 : FAIL : 
NoSuchWindowException: Message: Unable to get browser

Comment: Setting the Local Intranet zone's Enable Protected Mode setting to true may solve Unable to get browser exception.

From  IE menu bar,
Select Tools > Internet Options and go to the Security tab.
Select each zone (Internet, Local intranet, Trusted sites, Restricted sites) and check the Enable Protected Mode check box.

Comment: @Shijo it didnt work.still the same issue.Same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Click Button    Close
    Sleep    2s
    Select Window    main
    Sleep    2s
    Unselect Frame
    Sleep    2s
```